# Transferring Data from a worksheet to another with conditions

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I hope you could help me. I am trying to copy certain data based on multiple index and specifications. I have described my question below:

Hi, i am a basic learner in VBA. I could move the whole data but can not do the conditioning format.

I currently do not have a code ready

I am looking to transfer data from worksheet 1 to worksheet 2, worksheet 3, worksheet 4 based on conditions:

```
copy cell D VALUE if worksheet 1  column A = "Are" 

(if column B = 2 (open worksheet 2), 
AND 
if column C = "You" paste the multiple values of column D in cells C12 TO C19
if column c = "me" paste the multiple values of column D in cell C20 TO C29

if column B = 3 (open worksheet 3), 
AND
if column C = "You" paste the multiple values of column D in cells C12 TO C19
if column c = "me" paste the multiple values of column D in cell C20 TO C29

if column B = 4 (open worksheet 4))  
AND 
if column C = "You" paste the multiple values of column D in cells C12 TO C19
if column c = "me" paste the multiple values of column D in cell C20 TO C29
```

*Thank!!*

Comment: Elaborate on 'multiple values of column C' e.g. cell A5 contains "Are", B5 contains 2 and C5 contains "You", do I copy **D5:D12** or **D5:K5** to C12:C19 on Sheet2?

Comment: Hi, if Column A, B and C met the conditions, column D may not have a specific cell range as the raw data may not have a specific structure. matched cell D value could be at D5, D75 or D350. I would say all the matching results of D to be copied into C12:C19 where as possible column D results will not go over 7. I hope this will help?

Comment: In my example, I would then copy D5 to C12 and continue searching (looping)?

Comment: Hi, this would definitely work if we know the exact location of D value in the first occurrence. can we code it to find the first matched cell value for D and then continue searching (looping)?. I wish I could add a sample of my worksheet, but i don't think I can do that.

Comment: Here can we say if conditions for A,B,C met for the row 'X' then copy the value in D of row 'x' into C12 and continue searching?

Answer (score 0):

## Split to Multiple Worksheets

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitToMultiWorksheets()

    Const cSheets As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3,Sheet4"
    Const cStr1 As String = "Are"
    Const cStr2 As String = "You"
    Const cStr3 As String = "me"
    Const cFirstR As Long = 1
    Const cCol1 As Variant = "A"
    Const cCol2 As Variant = "B"
    Const cCol3 As Variant = "C"
    Const cCol4 As Variant = "D"
    Const cFirst1 As Long = 12
    Const cFirst2 As Long = 20

    'Const cLast1  As Long = 19
    'Const cLast2 As Long = 29

    Dim vntSheets As Variant
    Dim vnt1(2) As Variant
    Dim vnt2(2) As Variant
    Dim lastR As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wsName As String
    Dim First1 As Long
    Dim First2 As Long


    vntSheets = Split(cSheets, ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(vnt1)
        vnt1(i) = cFirst1 - 1
        vnt2(i) = cFirst2 - 1
    Next

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(vntSheets(0))
        lastR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cCol1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = cFirstR To lastR
            If .Cells(i, cCol1) = cStr1 Then
                wsName = vntSheets(.Cells(i, cCol2) - 1)
                Select Case .Cells(i, cCol3)
                    Case cStr2
                        First1 = vnt1(.Cells(i, cCol2) - 2) + 1
                        vnt1(.Cells(i, cCol2) - 2) = First1
                        .Parent.Worksheets(wsName).Cells(First1, cCol3) _
                                = .Cells(i, cCol4)
                    Case cStr3
                        First2 = vnt2(.Cells(i, cCol2) - 2) + 1
                        vnt2(.Cells(i, cCol2) - 2) = First2
                        .Parent.Worksheets(wsName).Cells(First2, cCol3) _
                                = .Cells(i, cCol4)
                End Select
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, VBasic2008. I get run time error 9 for "wsName = vntSheets(.Cells(i, cCol2) - 1)". Would you be able to help?

Comment: @V. Malla: The first line 'Const cSheets As String = "Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3,Sheet4"' has to contain the sheet names, the names in the tabs.

Comment: Hi, VBasic2008. My sheet names are Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3,Sheet4. But in "wsName = vntSheets(.Cells(i, cCol2) - 1)", I put 'Sheet1' in 'wsName', as I believe its representing the source data sheet.